# How to tell CPAN about path to make and cc

Tags: perl, cpan, solaris-10

Running Perl 5.10 CPAN on Solaris with opencsw.org packages, Makefile.PL from packages can't find the correct path and cc (gcc).

I found the path to make and set it to gmake, but I can't find any setting for cc.

I thought I once set this in CPAN/Config.pm (or with o config ...) but can no longer find any setting and don't have enough patience to wade through the thicket to figure out where such a basic thing gets set.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 10):

`cpan` doesn't need to know where `gcc` or equivalent is, because it isn't `cpan`'s job to call it directly. Usually it's `Makefile.PL` or `Build.PL` that needs to know that, and it usually will accept the compiler to use as a command line argument. If you add `PERLMAINCC=/compiler/to/use` to `o conf makepl_arg` that should do it.

Comment: Config.pm is where this gets set and will determine what each Makefile.PL sees.  But you answered my question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Extensions need to be built with the same tools as Perl itself, and Perl remembers what those tools are.

If you have since deleted or moved them, that could be a problem.

But more likely, you haven't installed the package(s) from your distro that provides them. Install the missing packages.

Comment: I'm on Solaris 10 and my distro is opencsw.org.  Perl 5.8 is from the original Solaris package, but Perl 5.10 which is first in my path is from OpenCSW.  I also have gcc and gmake installed and can run them from the command-line.

Answer (score 2):

In [`cpan_home`](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/CPAN/CPAN/HandleConfig.pm.html#cpan_home-)`/CPAN/Config.pm` (or via `o conf`):

```
'make_arg' => q[CC=/path/to/c-compiler]
```

Comment: Ran into this problem in a cluster environment trying to build Net::SSLeay where the system `cc` was too old and didn't support the `-fstack-protector-strong` option. Setting `make_arg` to `CC=gcc` (a newer version in my `$PATH`) was the correct solution in this case.